# How to search for a string in the external source iframe?

Tags: iframe

I'm trying to find a way to search the contents of the external iframe.. How to do that?

I know that I can't traverse the external iframe using javascript.., but what about PHP? Can I implement a script in PHP that will scan the contents of the external iframe? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `cUrl` (or maybe `fread`) to read the contents of the url that is in the `src` of your `iframe`, but there is no garantee that the contents will be the same. The page that is rendered inside the iframe might depend on session data, cookies, referee...

Comment: the problem is, when i tried to use curl the website that i tried to put in an iframe didnt work.. because it thinks that im using a differen kind of browser.. i think this has to do with tricking the website by specifying that im using a google chrome browser by browser agent?

Comment: If it *only* depends on the browser/user agent you can do that, yes.

Comment: the website that im trying to scan is facebook.. they have facebook like box social plugin and i want to find out if the reader that is using my website have already liked my page.. apparently facebook didnt implement a method in knowing that easily

Comment: Then, you probably cannot. When you retreive the content of that url, from PHP, you don't have the session data associated with that facebook page, so when you load it, you will see different content.

Comment: There is however another way to embed the like button on your page, and it doesn't use an iframe. Maybe you have more possibilities when you use this (See `JavaScript version` on http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/04/adding-facebook-like-buttons-to-your-site-is-damn-easy/ )

Comment: oh i forgot about sessions.. so using curl is out.. here's the url of the stuff: "http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fplatform&amp;width=292&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;connections=10&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true&amp;height=587" as you can see you can point your browser url there and the plugin still works.. what about screen scraping? i just want to know if the user already like the page or not..

Comment: No, it's not possible, even though the iframe is contained in your page, it is actually a separate browser window. You can't get its contents. That would be undesirable from a privacy point of view. If it was possible for a page to read the contents of an iframe, you could embed any sort of website in your page and retreive all kinds of sensitive information about your visitors. Maybe there is a way if you use the javascript api, but it cannot be done using iframes.